# スライディングメニューのjQueryでの実装

Tags: onsen-ui

パターン http://ja.onsen.io/patterns.html の中で、Sliding Menuをangularではなく、jQueryで実装することはできますか。そのサンプルはどこかに示されていますか。

Answer (score 1):

`ons〜`がangularのdirectiveなので、jQueryで実装するのであればその辺はほとんど使えないのではないかと思います。

[Open panel on swipe](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/examples/panels/panel-swipe-open.html)
この辺のソースを参考にしたり、
[横からスライドするドロワーメニューのjQuery、JS、CSS3のプラグインまとめ！](http://webdesignmagazine.net/javascript/drawer/)
この辺から用途にあったプラグインを見つけられればいけそうな気がします。